# How to select sharednamespace

Tags: c#, mailkit, mimekit

Using IMAP - We have many shared mailboxes under the shared 'user' namespace with a '.' delimiter.

I'm trying to write some software that will migrate these shared mailboxes to Exchange server.

I'm trying to open a specific mailbox/folder within the 'user' shared namespace to which the IMAP server responds NO to the SELECT. Opening up using the commented excerpt below, for Inbox works just fine. Probably because I don't have access to the 'root/base-user folder' but I need to specify the child folder, I have no idea how to connect to the shared mailbox in question. For example it would be 'user.sharedmailboxA'

Forgive my terminology here, total noob with IMAP! Thanks

The following code excepts with "NO", presumably access denied when I try and try the Open method:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var client = new ImapClient())
            {
                client.Connect("imap.c.com", 993, true);
            // Note: since we don't have an OAuth2 token, disable
            // the XOAUTH2 authentication mechanism.
            client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");

            client.Authenticate("aa", "sdfdsf");

            var user_namespace = client.GetFolder(client.SharedNamespaces[0] );
            user_namespace.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);


            // The Inbox folder is always available on all IMAP servers...

            //var inbox = client.Inbox;
            //inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);

            //Console.WriteLine("Total messages: {0}", inbox.Count);
            //Console.WriteLine("Recent messages: {0}", inbox.Recent);

            //for (int i = 0; i < inbox.Count; i++)
            //{
            //    var message = inbox.GetMessage(i);
            //    Console.WriteLine("Subject: {0}", message.Subject);
            //}

            //client.Disconnect(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IMAP, you can't always select a folder. Sometimes it has the `\NoSelect` or `\NonExistent` attribute which will both fail with a NO if you try to select them.

In general, you cannot open namespace folders (the typical exception to this is when the INBOX is considered a namespace on IMAP servers such as Courier IMAP).

What you need to do is query the subfolders of `user_namespace` and try selecting one of *those* folders (assuming it doesn't have the `FolderAttributes.NoSelect` or `FolderAttributes.NonExistent` attributes):

```
foreach (var folder in user_namespace.GetSubfolders (false)) {
    if ((folder.Attributes & (FolderAttributes.NoSelect | FolderAttributes.NonExistent)) == 0))
        folder.Open (FolderAccess.ReadOnly);
}
```